# Swift protocol or abstract class similar to EqualityComparer<T>

Tags: swift, equality

Is there any Procotol or abstract class similar to EqualityComparer in Swift language?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.equalitycomparer-1?view=netcore-3.1